# Only want to updated first 26 records in a table using UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm trying to updated values for records in an attribute table. All records have a quadrant number (in field "Quadrant") and a random integer (in field "RandomSeg") assigned to them. I want to tag a subset of the data in the following way:

1. All records are sorted in ascending order according to the random integer (RandomSeg)
2. Next, I want to select all records within the first quadrant, then select only the first 26 records and tag them (as "1" in the "Sample" field).
3. Lastly, I wanted to repeat this for all quadrants so that in the end I have tagged records.

I can't figure out how to only update the first 26 records. Here's what I tried:

```
quadrants = [1,2,3,4]
for quadrant in quadrants:
    query=(f"Quadrant={quadrant}")
    cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(ft_class, where_clause=query, sort_fields="RandomSeg A")
    for row in cursor:
        row = 1
        while row<26:
            cursor.setValue("Sample", "1")
            cursor.UpdateRow(row)
            row+=1
```

I'm a beginner with Python so this may have all kinds of syntax errors.

Comment: First thing... do NOT use `arcpy.UpdateCursor()`.  It is effectively deprecated.  Use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` instead.  It works a little differently, but is vastly more efficient, and is the currently preferred method.  See:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm

Comment: If your code has "all kinds of syntax errors" then you should have tried to resolve them before coming here (since that's out of scope for a GIS question). You really ought to be using a DA UpdateCursor, with `enumerate()` (as in `for i,row in enumerate(cursor):` to count records. Right now, you just destroy the content of the `row` object, changing it into an integer, then access a non-existent `setValue` method on `cursor`. Always use code patterns from the documentation until you understand how things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code snippet below meets your requirements:

```
ft_class = r"..." # Your featureclass
quadrants = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for quadrant in quadrants:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ft_class, ["Sample"], f"Quadrant = {quadrant}", sql_clause=(None, "ORDER BY RandomSeg")) as cursor:
        for index, row in enumerate(cursor):
            if index >= 26:
                break
            row[0] = "1"
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Points for you to know:

- In your code you override the variable `row` every loop, which should be used as the row in the table.
- You're using an old version of `UpdateCursor`. My solution refers to the new version of it which is different from the old version.I recommend reading the documentation on the subject to understand: [UpdateCursor—ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

Comment: According to [UpdateCursor - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm), SQL `TOP` is only supported by SQL Server.  Since the OP didn't state they are using SQL Server, it is unlikely they are, so this answer will not work.

Comment: Thank you! This worked!

Answer (score 1):

As several others have mentioned, it is best to use the Data Access cursors ([UpdateCursor - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)) rather than the original ArcPy cursors.

Although a previous answer using SQL `TOP` will work if the back-end data source is Microsoft SQL Server, using `TOP` won't work for other back-end data sources.  A more portable approach involves using Python's built-in [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function (as mentioned by Vince in a comment).

```py
quadrants = [1,2,3,4]
for quadrant in quadrants:
    query=(f"Quadrant={quadrant}")
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ft_class, "Sample", sql_clause=(None, "ORDER BY RandomSeg")) as cur:
        for i,row in enumerate(cur):
            if i==26: break
            cur.updateRow([1])
```

Comment: I'd do `if i==26: break`, if there are many records you don't want to enumerate the rest

Comment: Agree, using break would be more efficient for large cursors.  I updated code snippet.